# OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite model once compiled in Nextjs and typescript

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I want create simply ecommerce project in nextjs and mongoose. I have error on early begning during creating models.

I have simply model like this

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface IProduct {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

const productSchema = new Schema<IProduct>({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
  },
});

export default mongoose.model<IProduct>('product', productSchema);
```

After runing project i gettint error `OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite` product `model once compiled.`

So i changed export to `export default mongoose.models.product || mongoose.model<IProduct>('product', productSchema);`.

After that everything seems to work but my models lost types sugestion and instead of

`const products: Product[] = await Product.find({});`

i have

`const products: any[] = await Product.find({});`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly use Mongoose models in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887351/how-to-properly-use-mongoose-models-in-next-js)

Comment: It was worked for first time, after page reload i get again error `Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot overwrite `Product` model once compiled.`

Comment: You need to cast the model to preferred type `export default (mongoose.models.product as IProduct) || mongoose.model<IProduct>('product', productSchema);`

Comment: It's not working because i getting different error - `TS2352: Conversion of type 'Model<any, {}, {}, {}, any, any>' to type 'IProduct' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.   Property 'price' is missing in type 'Model<any, {}, {}, {}, any, any>' but required in type 'IProduct'.`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
export const Product: mongoose.Model<IProduct> = mongoose.models.product || mongoose.model<IProduct>('product', productSchema);
```